# Numbering cells from different sheets

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I would like to automatically count cells if other cells from a different sheets aren't empty.

So here is the thing. I have sheet 1 called "Monday" that has some value (Apple) in cell A1.
In sheet 2 called "Tuesday", cell A1 is empty, so it doesn't have any value.
In sheet 3 "Wednesday", cell A1 also has some other value (Banana).
In sheet 4 "Thursday", cell A1 also has some value (Peach).
In sheet 5 called "Total", I have a summary of all sheets.

What I want to do is that in sheet "Total", it counts all A1 cells from the other sheets (Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday) that have any value in it, meaning they aren't blank.

The thing is, that in the sheet "Total" I have 4 columns, and each column represents different sheet ("Monday"-"Thursday"). So, when I have value "Apple" in sheet "Monday", I wan't it to show me a value of "1" in column "Monday" of sheet "Total", and so on...

So in "Total" it would show me:
Monday - 1, 
Tuesday - "blank"
Wednesday - 2
Thursday - 3.

I hope you understand what I want, and will find an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `COUNTA` function to count non-blank cells. Then use a [3-D reference](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-reference-to-the-same-cell-range-on-multiple-worksheets-c906f8b4-c648-4aa0-8063-65d38d03370f) to get the values of the `A1` cell in the range of sheets.

You end up with the following formula to solve your problem:

`=COUNTA(Monday:Thursday!A1)`

(This assumes that sheets you listed are in order with no other sheets in-between.)

Comment: Woah I didn't know you could do that. +1 for the 3D reference